# parallel azure blob upload get warning 'urllib3.connectionpool WARNING - Connection pool is full, discarding connection'

Tags: python, multithreading, azure, azure-blob-storage, urllib3

Since I need to upload a large number of files over 100000 to azure blob storage, I wrote a program to upload by multi-thread processing like this.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient
from itertools import repeat
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import os

def upload_single_blob(blob_service_client, blob_path):
    # Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container='MyContainer', 
    blob=blob_path)

    # Upload the file
    with open(blob_path, "rb") as data:
        blob_client.upload_blob(data)

# make blob service client from connect str
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
# make file path list to upload
blob_path_list = os.listdir("./blob_files/")
blob_path_list = map(lambda x: "./blob_files/"+x, blob_path_list)
blob_path_list = list(blob_path_list)

# multi threading upload to blob
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    executor.map(upload_single_blob, repeat(blob_service_client), blob_path_list)
```

However, when I ran this program at azure VM (OS is ubuntu18.04), I got the warning a lot.

```
urllib3.connectionpool WARNING --Connection pool is full, discarding connection: myblobaccount.blob.core.windows.net
```

I didn't measure it accurately, but it seemed that there were only about 10 connections at the same time, even though uploading in parallel with 100 threads.

How can I increase the number of connections any more?

Answer (score 0):

Many Azure classes support a `session` keyword argument that can be used to provide a custom `requests.Session` object that azure uses internally to handle requests. In your case, you can probably do something similar to the following:

```py
import requests

# manually create a requests session
session = requests.Session()
# set an adapter with the required pool size
adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(pool_maxsize=100)
# mount the adapter to the session
session.mount('https://', adapter)

# use custom session object
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str, session=session)
```